# Distance between theorems

Tags: reference-request, logic, information-theory, automated-theorem-proving

In automated proving one can define the *best* proof of a theorem as the one which minimizes the length of the proof. Given a set of known statements one could define the *difficulty* of a theorem as the minimum length among all its proofs deduced from known statements. One could also define the *importance* of a theorem $T$ in a set of statements as the inverse of the sum of the difficulty of all the remaining theorems known $T$.

Even in a setting not as formal as automated proving these ideas seem very natural to me.

**My question**:

> Has anyone ever elaborated a satisfactory theory of distance between/difficulty of/importance of/etc. of theorems?

Comment: Hilbert published his famous $23$ problems and an additional one : Can a proof of a claim be proven to be the shortest possible proof ? I do not know, if some progress was achieved. In principal, the shortest proof can be found (if some proof is given) by checking all valid expressions not longer than the given proof, if they are a valid proof. But this approach would be unfeasible in practice.

Comment: @Peter You might want to see Robert Veroff's "Finding Shortest Proofs: An Application of Linked Inference Rules" which you can read in Postscript format via his website: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~veroff/

Comment: @Brainstorming : yes I agree with you it's very natural, forget what others answered. 

then the difficulty of proving a theorem becomes dependant on the algorithm you choose to try proving unkown theorems. every mathematician is obviously an implemtation of some sort of automatic theorem prover, and for some mathematicians a theorem is very easy to solve whereas for others it will take 10 years : this is because, even if their knowledge is supposed to be the same, the way they will make sub-problems and will approach the "theorem solving problem" is different..

Comment: @Brainstorming : given an "automatic theorem proving algorithm", the difficulty of a theorem is just an increasing function of the time and the memory spent to prove the theorem. if you suppose that time can be converted to memory, then you got precisely the function. in real world, we consider that time cannot be converted to memory, thus many difficulty functions are allowed, and choosing one will depend on the heuristics you want to get from it.

Answer (score 1):

"Given a set of known statements one could define the difficulty of a theorem as the minimum length among all its proofs deduced from known statements. One could also define the importance of a theorem T in a set of statements as the inverse of the sum of the difficulty of all the remaining theorems known T."

In even axiomatic propositional calculi it's known that the set of all remaining theorem is infinite.  Since the difficulty of all theorems is positive for each theorem, this implies that every theorem in say 2-valued or any other axiomatic proposition calculus has an infinite importance.

You might want to think that all those remaining theorems aren't known.  And in some sense that comes as correct.  However, there do exist infinite patterns of theorems which are knowable in some sense.  For example, under condensed detachment as a rule of inference, if CpCqp is an axiom or theorem ("thesis" hereafter), then we have this infinite pattern of theses:

{CpCqp, Cp$_1$CpCqp, Cp$_2$Cp$_1$CpCqp ... }

And you can prefix an infinite sequence of theses in a similar manner.

Another pattern is the sequence of theses derivable using condensed detachment where CCpqCCqrCpr is always the major premise in say any system where "C" is the main connective for every axiom.  Since "Cpq" unifies with every axiom, and by using condensed detachment you generate a conditional of the form CC$\alpha$$\beta$C$\gamma$$\beta$, Cpq unifies with every theses in this sequence.  Using D notation it goes 
(1, D1.1 = 2, D1.2 = 3, D1.3 = 4...)  Another knowable pattern of theses starts with CCpqCCrpCrq and behaves similarly to the previous pattern.

Robert Veroff did some work on finding shortest proofs in propositional calculi systematically (Larry Wos has spent years searching for short proofs with theorem provers, but there exist very few proofs which have seem to have gotten proved to be the shortest).  You might want to see his paper which you can get read in Postscript format as his website:

[Finding Shortest Proofs: An Application of Linked Inference Rules](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~veroff/)